# resample pandas dataframe from 15min interval to daily based on max value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a few months worth of timeseries weather data based on 15min intervals.
Small sample from one day below:

```
    Date/Time          avg_temp avg_humid
0   2021-06-30 23:45:00 17.94   99.9
1   2021-06-30 23:30:00 17.94   99.9
2   2021-06-30 23:15:00 18.06   99.5
3   2021-06-30 23:00:00 18.11   98.7
4   2021-06-30 22:45:00 18.09   98.2
```

Using pandas dataframe I would like to convert the data to daily frequency and only keep the maximum "avg_temp" value for that day and the corresponding "avg_humid"

so for above sample I want to get new dataframe

```
    Date        max_avg_temp    max_avg_humid

    2021-06-30        18.11       98.7
```

have tried this

```
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df['Date/Time'],format="%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S")
df.resample("d")['avg_temp'].max()
```

which results in:

```
2021-06-30        18.11
```

but not the corresponding humidity.

so in summary, two questions:

1. how would one achieve above resampling ?
2. for date/time format such as "2021-06-30 23:45:00" as an index, how do you sort the index in pandas so its ascending and factoring in date and time in the sorting?

Comment: Can you explain more `for date/time format such as "2021-06-30 23:45:00" as an index, how do you sort the index in pandas so its ascending and factoring in date and time in the sorting?` ?

Answer (score 2):

Use [`DataFrameGroupBy.idxmax`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.idxmax.html) for indices by maximal values, so possible select matched rows by [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html), last remove times by [`Series.dt.normalize`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.normalize.html) or [`Series.dt.date`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.date.html):

```
df['Date/Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date/Time'])

df1 = df.loc[df.resample("d", on='Date/Time')['avg_temp'].idxmax()] 
#datetimes - times are set to 00:00:00
df1['Date/Time'] = df1['Date/Time'].dt.normalize() 
#dates
#df1['Date/Time'] = df1['Date/Time'].dt.date
   Date/Time  avg_temp  avg_humid
3 2021-06-30     18.11       98.7
```

Or:

```
df['Date/Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date/Time'])
df = df.set_index('Date/Time')

df1 = df.loc[df.resample("d")['avg_temp'].idxmax()] 
df1.index = df1.index.normalize() 
print (df1)
            avg_temp  avg_humid
Date/Time                      
2021-06-30     18.11       98.7
```